# Store ID in var with puppetteer and use it with page.await

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, puppeteer, element

So I was trying to code something when I found out the ID of the Element I used was changing everytime the website reloads. I fixed it by getting the id from the login form it cam from like this :

```
var login = document.getElementById('loginForm')[1].id
```

I then wanted to type something in this form using the id like this:

```
await page.type('#' + login, "mytext");
```

The problem is it reurns an error, so I tried using a different technique like this:

```
await page.type([id= login], "mytext");
```

And even this didn't work, and please don't answer with "Just set the value of the ID to your text!" this wouldn't work because the page will realize that you aren't an actual person. Any help is appreciated, been sitting on this problem for a while, so thanks for all answers.

Comment: You need to share what error you got, that's the key here.

Comment: I got No node found for selector error, which doesn't make much sense since the same command works perfectly fine in the dev console of the page.